# How do I install proprietary drivers for my Brother all-in-one printer/scanner/fax?

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, brother, fax

Guides on how to install drivers for a Brother all-in-one network printer are either for older devices or are rather complicated as they often involve editing or copying system files in my root directory.

Is there a newer, more convenient way to install the drivers needed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For presently supported devices Brother provide an install script that both, downloads and installs all drivers needed to set up a network printer very quickly.

1. **Set up the network connection**

   - First set up your wireless connection on the printer display according to the quick setup manual. **Note down your printer's IP as we need it later.**
2. **Install the proprietary drivers from Brother**

   - Browse to [Brother Support](http://support.brother.com/) and search for your model number.
   - Search for Linux (deb) drivers:

     [image]

     <sup>In case we have a locale different from English we may have to ignore a warning to then select *Language > English>*</sup>
   - Download the **Driver Install Tool** only (no need to download the other drivers as the installer tool will do that for you).
   - Unpack the downloaded file and give it executable permission

     ```
     cd ~/Downloads ## or the path you had stored the download
     gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
     chmod +x linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
     ```
   - Run the installer script in a terminal with sudo:

     ```
     sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
     ```

     We will be asked to proceed, accept licenses and we will need to answer several questions, e.g.:

     - **`Input model name ->`** type in the number of your printer (e.g. `MFC-J5320DW`)
     - Missing dependencies will be installed from the repositories
     - **`Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->`** Say `Y` if your printer was installed in the network (`n` for USB only).
     - Type in the number of your new printer's URI (e.g. `12` in the example below) from a list of all devices found

       ```
            ..
            12: dnssd://Brother%20MFC-J5320DW._ipp._tcp.local/
            ..
       ```
     - Choose to print an Ubuntu print test page with `Y`
     - **`enter IP address ->`** enter here the IP address of your printer noted above to enable network scanning.
     - **Done!**
     - Find uninstaller scripts in the download directory in case we need those later.
3. **Find your new printer in the *System Settings > Printers*.**

   - Optionally choose to make it your default printer, and adjust the default properties (e.g. paper size etc.).
4. **Install the fax function if available.**

   - Some Brother all-in-one printers also have an inbuilt fax but the drivers will not be shown on the printer driver download page.
   - Choose the general purpose Brother fax driver for any Brother fax model to download the LPR and CUPS wrapper drivers from their DEB package, e.g.:

     ```
     brmfcfaxcups-1.0.0-1.i386.deb
     brmfcfaxlpd-1.0.0-1.i386.deb
     ```

   These drivers will likely also work with your printer's fax module by  adding a `BRFAX`-printer for sending a fax from any application.

*Note in addition:* Some devices will come with a maintenance web-interface we can reach simply by browsing to the printer's IP.

Comment: Excellent answer! Worked for my `DCP-L2530DW`! Just make sure there are no spaces in the path where you downloaded the drivers before running the installer script. Otherwise, you will notice some errors such as: `cp: cannot stat '<some path>': No such file or directory` and `dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive 'dcpl2530dwpdrv-4.0.0-1.i386.deb': No such file or directory`...

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 TLS 64bit and my printer is a DCP-L2520DW and it isn't connected to my laptop directly.

These steps are for install the printer over the network (of course, you have to set-up your printer wifi first).

Before you start, these drivers depend on libstdc++6 or ia32-libs. In my case, I managed to install libstdc++6 after fixing some conflicts executing this commands (try first only with the last one):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

1) Open http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcpl2520dw_us_eu and select Linux and Linux(deb)

NOTE: I tried with **Driver Install Tool** with no luck :-(

2) Download **LPR printer driver (deb package)**

3) Install printer drivers: open the console and go to the folder where you download your drivers and then:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all dcpl2520dwlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
```

WHERE: *dcpl2520dwlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb* is the name of my drivers, be sure you match yours

4) Check your drivers are installed

```
dpkg -l | grep Brother
```

5) Edit /etc/printcap and replace ":lp" line to the following 2 lines:

```
:rm=(ip address of your printer)\
:rp=lp\
```

6) Re-start your printer service

```
sudo service cups restart
```

7) Install printer manually and change device URI:

```
ipp://<<yourip>>:631/binary_p1
```

**STEPS TO INSTALL SCANNER DRIVERS**

1) Download scanner driver from: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcpl2520dw_us_eu&os=128&dlid=dlf006645_000&flang=4&type3=566

2) Install scanner driver

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.4-4.amd64.deb
```

3) Check driver is installed

```
dpkg -l | grep Brother
```

4) Install scanner

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=<<friendy-name-you-want>> model=DCP-L2520DW ip=<<yourip>>
```

5) Execute xsane to check everything is OK

Answer (score 1):

Worked using  hl2280dw drivers on HL-2280DW printer. Printer had previously been installed under Win 10, and had an assigned IP address.

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2280dw_us&os=128

Running Linux Mint 17.2 as VirtualBox Guest, Windows 10 host.Mint 17.2 is based on Ubuntu so I downloaded the .deb file from above link,
then sudo bash

During driver install, I needed the ip of the printer. To obtain, on printer 
MENU/Machine Info/Network Config/Start.

Install downloaded many packages, took 2 or 3 minutes.

Verified wireless printing works from gedit. Wireless scanning works with 'Simple Scan' (default in Mint). However, pushing Scan button on printer did not identify Mint installation as possible destination, but I can live with that.  May need another driver running in Mint for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Brother MFC-J460DW, and this worked as the simplest way to get it going:

Download the Brother driver install tool for [your specific model], and for "Linux (deb)" from:

http://support.brother.com/

Go to 'Files' and open the folder where the file downloaded to.

Open 'Terminal', get superuser authorization with the `sudo su` command, and enter password.

Type or paste into 'Terminal': `gunzip` (with a space) then drag and drop the [example] `linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz` file into 'Terminal', and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Type or paste into 'Terminal': `bash` (With a space) then drag and drop the new unzipped file [example] `linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1` into 'Terminal', and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This should start the Brother Install program, which will guide you through completion.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a Brother MFC-L3770CDW connected by LAN. I downloaded and run the install script from the Brother website. I was in doubt which URI to chose. It worked after I chose `lpd://BRNB422005D4561/BINARY_P1`. I entered the IP address that shows on the printer's display in the network settings.