# Brother MFC-6490cw driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I have a brother MFC-6490CW printer and I am unable to connect to it through my wireless network using ubuntu 14.04 due to not having a driver available... does the driver exist? if it does, how do I find/install it? thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install proprietary drivers for my Brother all-in-one printer/scanner/fax?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/636363/how-do-i-install-proprietary-drivers-for-my-brother-all-in-one-printer-scanner-f)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do exist, I have been using my MFC6490CW with Ubuntu since 2009, both for printing and scanning.

You can download the driver e.g. from the [US support site](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc6490cw_all). Select the deb versions. I have used the individual drivers, but you might want to try the 
`Driver Install Tool` (listed at the top [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc6490cw_all&os=128)) download it and follow its installation instructions:

> Step1. Download the tool.(linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz)
>
> The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory.
>   (The directory location varies depending on your Linux distribution.)
>   e.g. /home/(LoginName)/Download
>
> Step2. Open a terminal window and go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step.
>
> Step3. Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:
>
> Command: gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz
>
> Step4. Get superuser authorization with the "su" command or "sudo su" command.
>
> Step5. Run the tool:
>
> Command: bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* Brother machine name
>
> Step6. The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.
>
> When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",
>
> For USB Users: Choose N(No)
>   For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI.
>
> The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete.