# Brother DCP-7070 does not scan

Tags: 14.04, scanner, brother

I have a problem with scanning on my Brother DCP-7070DWR, Ubuntu 14.04 via GUI software like xsane or simplescan

My printer connected via wifi. I have succesfully install printer and scanner Brother's drivers. Printing works just fine. But I can not scanning - xsane telling me "No devices available" (from root too)

Scanimage test show me all ok:

```
vito@vws:~$  scanimage -d test -T
scanimage: scanning image of size 157x196 pixels at 8 bits/pixel
scanimage: acquiring gray frame, 8 bits/sample
scanimage: reading one scanline, 157 bytes...    PASS
scanimage: reading one byte...        PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 2 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 4 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 8 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 16 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 32 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 64 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 128 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 256 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 255 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 127 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 63 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 31 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 15 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 7 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 3 bytes...     PASS
```

This is brother's drivers installed on my computer:

```
vito@vws:/opt/lampp/htdocs/qoot$ dpkg -l | grep -i brother
ii brgenml1cupswrapper 3.1.0-1 i386 Brother BrGenML1 CUPS wrapper driver
ii brgenml1lpr 3.1.0-1 i386 Brother BrGenML1 LPR driver
ii brscan-skey 0.2.4-1 i386 Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii brscan4 0.4.3-1 i386 Brother Scanner Driver
ii printer-driver-ptouch 1.3-8 i386 printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

But sane-find-scanner util shows me some pipe trouble:

```
vito@vws:~$ sudo sane-find-scanner


  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.


  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.


could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.


  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.


  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

However, I run evaluated VueScan - and it scans perfectly out of the box. Please give me some ideas how to fix xsane working.

Please note that installed VueScan scanning software works good (scans successfully), so seems it is not IP address issue. But xsane/simplescan does not work and this is a problem (cause it is a free software)

Comment: Did you also install the [Brother Scanner settings package](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp7070dw_eu&os=128&dlid=dlf006654_000&flang=4&type3=600)? Much easier is installing using the custom script from Brother - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/636363/how-do-i-install-proprietary-drivers-for-my-brother-all-in-one-printer-scanner-f

Comment: Yes, I have succesfully installed printer and scanner Brother's drivers, from support.brother.com as your link suggests

Comment: ...and Brother Scanner settings package too. XSane says "no devices available"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. 
Get scanner's IP Address by using the Menu button on the printer/scanner, select Network, then TCP / IP, then IP Address. Ping it:

```
brsaneconfig4 -p 192.168.0.107
```

not any answer in my case. So I set my scanner IP by brsaneconfig:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=DCP-7070DW model=DCP7070DW ip=192.168.0.107
```

Then restart computer and ping again. Ping now works fine and xsane detects scanner successfully.

Comment: OMG! It worked! I've been looking for a solution this for ages! thanks. You should accept your own answer.