# Install Brother driver

Tags: printing

Which variant of Brother's Linux printer driver ("rpm" or "deb") is best for model HL5450DN mono laser printer for Ubuntu 15X or 14X versions?

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/636363/how-do-i-install-proprietary-drivers-for-my-brother-all-in-one-printer-scanner-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary:

For Ubuntu, you always go with `.deb` files!
Also make sure its description matches your Ubuntu's version number or codename (e.g. `14.04` or `trusty`) and architecture (32bit=`i386` or 64bit=`amd_64`).

## Explanation:

Ubuntu is based on *Debian Linux*. Debian uses the `deb` package system, which all of its derivates adopted.
You can use the tool `dpkg` to install a `.deb` package on Ubuntu:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb
```

If possible, you should prefer software from an official repository or at least PPA that you can install with `apt-get`, `aptitude` or a GUI tool like the Software-Center or Synaptic.

---

The RPM (RedHat Package Management) system is a different package system for other Linux distributions, i.e. *RedHat Linux* and its derivates. They're incompatible with the `deb` packages used by Debian and Ubuntu.
However, it's still sometimes possible to convert `.rpm` packages into `.deb` packages using the tool `alien`, so that you can install it. This fails for packages with deep system integration though, because those are often highly adapted to the specific distribution and therefore unable to run anywhere else.

Comment: @peabody As you're a new user here, please click the grey tick on the left of this answer, if it fully solved your problem. That "accepts" the answer and shows others that this was the one that helped you most and that your question is answered. Make sure you've also read through the [tour] of AskUbuntu, which shows you the basics of how this site works within just about 2 minutes. Thanks and welcome on this great website!

Answer (score 0):

You can not install rpm package in Ubuntu. 
Get a deb package that exactly corresponds your Ubuntu version and architecture.