# how to install brother mfc-j4420dw?

Tags: printing, brother

show me please how to install brother mfc-j4420dw on Ubuntu 14.04, thank you!
i tried to open the cd but it showed me an error.
and i didn't understand the guide on their website.

Comment: You should add error in this question

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/636363/how-do-i-install-proprietary-drivers-for-my-brother-all-in-one-printer-scanner-f

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brother-cups* brother-lpr*
```

If these packages are not available, you need to enable the universe/multiverse repositories.

The above should install the following packages plus dependencies:

```
brother-cups-wrapper-ac - Cups Wrapper drivers for ac brother printers
brother-cups-wrapper-bh7 - Cups Wrapper drivers for bh7 brother printers
brother-cups-wrapper-common - Common files for Brother cups wrapper packages
brother-cups-wrapper-extra - Cups Wrapper drivers for extra brother printers
brother-cups-wrapper-laser - Cups Wrapper drivers for laser brother printers
brother-cups-wrapper-laser1 - Cups Wrapper drivers for laser1 brother printers
brother-cups-wrapper-mfc9420cn - Cups Wrapper drivers for mfc9420cn brother printers
brother-lpr-drivers-ac - LPR drivers for ac brother printers
brother-lpr-drivers-bh7 - LPR drivers for bh7 brother printers
brother-lpr-drivers-common - Common files for brother-lpr-drivers packages
brother-lpr-drivers-extra - LPR drivers for extra brother printers
brother-lpr-drivers-laser - LPR drivers for laser brother printers
brother-lpr-drivers-laser1 - LPR drivers for laser1 brother printers
brother-lpr-drivers-mfc9420cn - LPR driver for mfc9420cn brother printer
```

Otherwise, contact Brother support by telephone and have them walk you through the process. You will need to install the linux "deb" versions and not the "rpm" ones.