# How to install Brother DCP-L2540DW Driver to Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

(New User to Ubuntu)

I have tried to follow [this steps](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=sg&lang=en&prod=dcpl2540dw_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625).
But I always cannot locate the file (always stuck in Step 2).

Please kindly assist me in install and the exact steps by steps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/a/636364/3940. The download goes to your `Downloads` folder by default but depending on your browser you can tell it to use any other location including your `Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

To go to the download directory simply open up a terminal (press CTRL+ALT+T) and type:

`cd ~/Downloads` [ENTER]

You should now be in the directory Downloads and should be able to proceed. If you get stuck again, just ask by adding a comment.

Good luck!