# Setup for Brother Printer HL-1112?

Tags: software-installation, printing, brother

Brother Printer HL-1112: Driver-Set Up (linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz)
This Driver is from Brother-Web-page.

How can I install it in the Linux-System ??

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/a/636364/3940

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the download is in your ~/Downloads directory

```
cd ~/Downloads
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz 
sudo -i
bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
```

Answer the questions it shows (printer model and type of connection are the 1st two) and wait for the installer to continue. Watch for error notices.

If all goes well check "Printers" and see if your model is listed and the let CUPS install it.

---

Requirements:

- wget
- glibc.i686/libstdc++
- cups
- you also need the IP address the printer is using.

---

The tar file only has 1 file in it and has some parameters you can change:

```
ENABLE_FAX_INSTALL=No           # change to Yes if FAX is required 
DEBUG_MSG=0
MSG=1
```

Comment: Sorry,no way I'm bringing the printer back...........Thanks

Comment: @tommy7733 advice: pick a printer from the hardware list https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters (also check the comments from users) ;-) And a HP printer always works (they support linux)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the printer now is working with Linux: But I was not shur ,bcause this tool from Ubuntu-HardwareSupportComponents was old and they told me damaged. So O.K. now thanks everybody........

Answer (score 0):

1) Right-click it. After it opens in Archive Manager, extract it to wherever you want

2) Open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)

3) `cd` to where you extracted the file.

4) `sudo su` - Type your password

5) `chmod +x linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1`

6) `./linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1`

Answer (score 0):

Another way: 
Install Brother drivers from their website: 
http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hl1112_us_eu

hl1110lpr
hl1110cupswrapper

Then ensure that also installed are:

brother-lpr-drivers-common 
brother-lpr-drivers-laser1
brother-cups-wrapper-common
brother-cups-wrapper-laser1
printer-driver-brlaser

Probably not all these five are necessary (you could experiment) but together they made my printer work.