# How do I install Brother printer drivers?

Tags: command-line, drivers, printing

Have read previous answers and they do not solve my problem. I downloaded Brother printer drivers. From file cabinet search found Downloads, Properties show it went to `/home/myname/Downloads`. Confirmed it did download by terminal command `ls Downloads`.

Upon terminal command:

```
myname@myname-computername:~$ cd DownloadsEnter
```

It returns this line:

```
myname@myname-computername:~/Downloads$
```

I have made sure of spelling, case, spacing, tried cycling through other directories and still get nothing. What exactly am I supposed to type after the `:~$`?

Brother instructions are:

- Download the tool (`linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz`).
- Go to directory you downloaded the file to in the last step. By using the `cd` command. e.g. `cd Downloads`
- Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

  ```
  gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz
  ```

  e.g.

  ```
  gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz
  ```

etc, etc

Comment: `cd` means change-directory. It worked as your default directory which was "~" (which is shorthand for /home/$USER or your /home/myname/ as you typed it) was changed to ~/Downloads, ie. your present.working.directory is /home/myname/Downloads (or $HOME/Downloads).  `cd` or change-directory did its job, what did you expect it to do?  (`cd` does the same as windows; microsoft used the xenix (their name for unix pre-msDOS days) command)

Comment: Can you post the exact file name you downloaded.

Comment: You may find further help here: [How do I install proprietary drivers for my Brother all-in-one printer/scanner/fax?](https://askubuntu.com/q/636363/507051)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the Downloads directory.

   ```
   cd Downloads
   ```

   The command prompt will change after running this command to show the new current working directory (`~/Downloads`).
2. List the contents of the Downloads directory to show the name of the Brother printer driver archive that you downloaded.

   ```
   ls
   ```
3. Extract the contents of the Brother printer driver archive that you downloaded.

   ```
   gunzip name-of-brother-driver.gz # replace name-of-brother-driver.gz with the name of the driver archive that you downloaded
   ```

   You can copy the name of the Brother printer driver archive that you downloaded from the results of `ls` in step 2 and paste it into the command in step 3 instead of *name-of-brother-driver.gz*.