# I cannot install my Brother HL 1212 w printer on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, brother

I'm trying to install my Brother HL1212w printer on Xubuntu 18.04 (64 bits) (notebook Lenovo ideapad 110-14IBR). I'm not trying the WiFi connection. I wouldn't know how to install it. Just the USB.

I followed [these instructions on Brother support](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=mx&lang=es&prod=hl1212w_us_eu&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625) and also [How do I install proprietary drivers for my Brother all-in-one printer/scanner/fax?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636363/how-do-i-install-proprietary-drivers-for-my-brother-all-in-one-printer-scanner-f/636364#636364) but neither of them worked.

```
anonimo@lenovo:~/Documentos/Informática/Impresora Brother HL 1212 w/2018-12-01$ sudo chmod +x linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1
anonimo@lenovo:~/Documentos/Informática/Impresora Brother HL 1212 w/2018-12-01$ sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1
Input model name ->hl1212w

You are going to install following packages.
   hl1210wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
   hl1210wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
OK? [y/N] ->y

Obj:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                            
Obj:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Descargados 247 kB en 4s (70,4 kB/s)                   
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete ia32-libs no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente
Sin embargo, los siguientes paquetes lo reemplazan:
  lib32ncurses5 lib32z1

E: El paquete «ia32-libs» no tiene un candidato para la instalación
dpkg -x hl1210wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb /
dpkg -x hl1210wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb /
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre '/home/anonimo/Documentos/Informática/Impresora': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'Brother': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'HL': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre '1212': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'w/2018-12-01/hl1210wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb': No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg-deb: error: fallo al leer el archivo `hl1210wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb': No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg-deb: error: fallo al leer el archivo `hl1210wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb': No existe el archivo o el directorio
./linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1: línea 2301: DEBIAN/control.tmp: No existe el archivo o el directorio
cat: DEBIAN/control: No existe el archivo o el directorio
mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'DEBIAN/control.tmp': No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg-deb: error: fallo al abrir el fichero de información del paquete `./brother_driver_packdir/DEBIAN/control' para leer: No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg -b ./brother_driver_packdir hl1210wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre '/home/anonimo/Documentos/Informática/Impresora': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'Brother': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'HL': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre '1212': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'w/2018-12-01/hl1210wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb': No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg-deb: error: fallo al leer el archivo `hl1210wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb': No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg-deb: error: fallo al leer el archivo `hl1210wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb': No existe el archivo o el directorio
./linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1: línea 2328: DEBIAN/control.tmp: No existe el archivo o el directorio
cat: DEBIAN/control: No existe el archivo o el directorio
mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'DEBIAN/control.tmp': No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg-deb: error: fallo al abrir el fichero de información del paquete `./brother_driver_packdir/DEBIAN/control' para leer: No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg -b ./brother_driver_packdir hl1210wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
mv: el objetivo 'w/2018-12-01' no es un directorio
mv: el objetivo 'w/2018-12-01' no es un directorio
./linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1: línea 2381: cd: demasiados argumentos
dpkg -i --force-all hl1210wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
dpkg: error: no se puede acceder al archivo 'hl1210wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb': No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg -i --force-all hl1210wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
dpkg: error: no se puede acceder al archivo 'hl1210wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb': No existe el archivo o el directorio
###############################ls: no se puede acceder a '/usr/share/ppd/*.ppd': No existe el archivo o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a '/usr/share/cups/model/*.ppd': No existe el archivo o el directorio
#
dpkg-query: el paquete `hl1210wlpr' no está instalado.
Utilice dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) para examinar archivos,
y dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) para listar su contenido.

0: ipps
1: cups-brf:/
2: beh
3: socket
4: lpd
5: serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
6: https
7: http
8: hp
9: ipp
10: usb://Brother/HL-1210W%20series?serial=U63982M6N669667
11: hpfax
12 (I): Specify IP address.
13 (A): Auto. (usb://Brother/HL-1210W%20series?serial=U63982M6N669667)

select the number of destination Device URI. ->13

Test Print? [y/N] ->y

wait 5s.
lpr -P HL1210W /usr/share/cups/data/testprint
Hit Enter/Return key.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution!

I was downloading the file "linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz" to other folder. But when I tried downloading it to "/home/user/Downloads/" everything worked well.

Hope it helps somebody else.

Andrew